# How to repack textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking

I have a model with ready-made materials and textures, but I need to cut this model into separate meshes, respectively, and the textures may no longer match, how can I rebake the textures?
(I only have diffusion and normals)

Or how can you cut the mesh and still not touch the texture?

[image: this is an example of what I got after cutting]

Comment: Separate mesh by using existing topology or keep original model, duplicate, split and Bake Selected to Active ...

Comment: Initially, I have one object (Human), it has five materials (head, body, arms...), I separate it by materials, this is what happens. As far as I understand, need to apply the DataTransfer, Normals, but something is not working so far...

Comment: everything figured out, it was necessary that the original model was in the same place ...